# 'cout << ...' или 'cout.put(...)'?

Tags: c++

Что лучше использовать для вывода на консоль символов: 'cout << ...' или 'cout.put(...)'?

Comment: По каким критериям надо оценивать?

Comment: Проверьте `<istream>`. Вполне вероятно, что второе вызывается из первого. Если это так, то оптимизатор встраивает вызов `operator>>`, и оба случая дают одинаковый машинный код.

Comment: Общее соображение - чем большим блоком писать, тем быстрее...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Функция-член класса `put` стандартного класса `basic_ostream`, объявленная как

```
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& put(char_type c)
```

предназначена только для объектов типа `char_type`, Она не перегружена для объектов других типов. Поэтому, например, чтобы написать эквивалентный вывод данным предложениям

```
int x = 10;

std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;
```

вам придется писать

```
int x = 10;

std::cout.put( 'x' ).put( ' ' ).put( '=' ).put( ' ' ) << x << std::endl;
```

что выглядит очень вычурно.

Внутренне такие функции, как, например, `std::endl` и `std::ends` используют функцию `put`. То есть эта функция считается функцией низшего уровня. В прикладных программах лучше использовать `operator <<` , который перегружен для всех стандартных типов и кроме того может быть перегружен для пользовательских типов. При этом код с использованием этого оператора выглядит более естественным и не вызывает вопросов.

На низшем уровне, например, когда вы реализуете свою функцию более высокого уровня, как, например, тот же самый оператор `operator <<` вы можете использовать функцию `put`.